# Save Changes with breeze Assembly could not be found for EntityName:#xx.xx.xx.xx.xx"

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

When saving changes, the follow Exception occurs:
   *"Assembly could not be found for EntityName:#xx.xx.xx.xx.Entities"*

**First 3 lines of Stack:**

- at Breeze.ContextProvider.ContextProvider.LookupEntityType(String entityTypeName)
- at Breeze.ContextProvider.SaveWorkState.<.ctor>b__8(IGrouping`2 g)
- at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()

**JS:**

```
function remove(entity) {
    entity.entityAspect.setDeleted();

    return this.manager
        .saveChanges()
        .then(ok, ko);
}
```

> What can be causing this issue?

Comment: This related  with my namespace prefix! My entities are not being probed as valid assemblies in Breeze.ContextProvider.IsFrameworkAssembly function.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

That exception happens if the Breeze ContextProvider cannot find a server-side class for the entity type you are trying to save.

When `manager.saveChanges` is called on the client, the JSON for each entity includes an `entityAspect` object with an `entityTypeName` property that is the fully-qualified class name of the entity.  This tells the server how to materialize the entity.

In your case, there is no class on the server matching the `entityTypeName` that your client is sending.

Comment: Hi Steve, the entityTypeName exists in server! The entity that i'm trying to save was retrived from server!
I can read this entities, however, I can't save them...

If I change the namesapce to a shorter one, i can make this work! why?

Comment: Hi Steve, after debug, using breeze source code, i have found that my entities are getting dropped from ProbeAssemblies in "IsFrameworkAssembly" check function... There is a way to workaround this "namespace check"?