# breeze saveChanges throws "Assembly could not be found" exception

Tags: breeze

I'm new to breezejs.
Someone please answer to this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954460/save-changes-with-breeze-assembly-could-not-be-found-for-entitynamexx-xx-xx-xx)
I have the exact same problem on ASP.NET WepAPI 2 and EntityFramework 6.3
this is my code:

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<TodoDBEntities> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<TodoDBEntities>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Todo> Todos()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Todos;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
}
```

it's a simple todo app with database first entity framework and default generate code.
I think I missed something in project setup or references.

Thank you very much.